# Left invariant forms on lie groups?

Tags: lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group. A vector field $X\in\mathfrak{X}(G)$ is **left-invariant** if the diagram below is commutative:

[image]

for every $g\in G$ where $L_g$ stands for the left translation by $g$. Now a differential $1$-form $\omega\in \Omega^1(G)$ is left invariant if $$L^*_g(\omega)=\omega,$$ for every $g\in G$ where $L_g^*(\omega)$ is the pullback form. Is there a way to define a left-invariant form using a commutative diagram as above (maybe using $T^*G$)?

Comment: What is the problem with drawing the same diagram, replacing $X$, $TG$ and $dL_g$ by $\omega$, $T^*G$ and $L_g^*$ respectively?

Comment: The problem is because $L_g^*$ is defined on $\Gamma(T^*G)=\Omega^1(G)$ and not on $T^*G$.